# If $P(X)$ be the power set of $X$ and and $ARB$ is a relation such that $A\cap B\neq \phi,$ Then Relation is

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$\bf{(1)}::$ Let $\bf{X}$ be the non-empty set and $\bf{P(X)}$ be the set of all subsets of $\bf{X}\;,$ for $\bf{A,B\in P(X)=}$

Power set of $\bf{X}$ and $\bf{ARB}$ Iff $\bf{A\cap B \neq \phi\;,}$ Then the relation is

Options::

$\bf{(a)}$ only Reflective $\bf{\;\;\;\;(b)}$ Only Symmetric $\bf{\;\;\;\;(c)}$ Only Transitive  $\bf{\;\;\;\;(c)}$ Equivalence Relation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clearly the relation isn't transitive: take $X = \{1,2,3,4\}$ and $A = \{1,2\}, B=\{2,3\}, C=\{3,4\}$. Then $A R B$ and $BRC$ but not $ ARC$. This rules out option c) and what should have been labeled option d).

The relation is not reflexive since $\emptyset R \emptyset$ doesn't hold. Therefore the answer is b).